# Published Facebook posts using the graph API are listed as Posted by Others

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, feed, publish

I am trying to post a message with a link on my Facebook page timeline. I tried the following (following Facebook docs):

```
curl -F 'access_token=XXX' -F 'message=Hello World!' -F 'link=http://www.stackoverflow.com' https://graph.facebook.com/my_page_ID/feed
```

The post was indeed published on my page. However, it was listed under **Recent Posts by Others** as opposed to be posted in the page's timeline.

If I omit the link parameter. The post is published fine in the timeline.

Any idea why my posts are published under **Recent Posts by Others**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still couldn't figure out the cause of the described issue but publishing a link instead displays my message in the timeline in the right place.